# ASP.NET Internationalization - global/shared resource key overrides

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, internationalization

I am using ASP.NET resource internationalization.

I have the following structure

```
 /App_LocalResources
     Default.aspx.resx

 /App_GlobalResources
     Commmon.resx
```

***Now what I was hoping for with ASP.Net resource is the ability override shared global keys within my local resource files.***

For instance if in my *Default.aspx* page and I have the following:

```
<asp:Literal Text="<%$ Resources:FirstName %>" runat="server" />
```

And I have *FirstName* in both my global resource file and local, I would expect the local key to override the shared but still fall through to global if it is not found in the local resource.

The problem I am finding is that being able to use the global resources requires that you provide the global resource filename.

```
<asp:Literal Text="<%$ Resources:Common,FirstName %>" runat="server" />
```

...which prevents you from being able to have a local override because of the explicit global filename declaration

I would hope there would be a way to specify a general key, and have it first search the local resources, and if not found there, then search through the global resources, without needing to specify a explicit global filename.

Is this possible, is there a way to attain this type of functionality from ASP.Net resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just isn't the way resources work in .NET AFAIK - I believe your best bet is going to be encapsulating the resource access is a getter method which can attempt to match a local resource for a given key before falling back to the global. Not pretty though.

Of course there's always the option of creating and using your own ResourceManager but from experience that's *much* more pain than you think.